# If a user runs libvirtd inside a docker container, is there any way to discover the user's VMs?

Tags: virtualization, docker, libvirt, containers

Potentially naive question that I'm hoping some `cgroups` experts can answer quickly:

Assuming the following `docker` workflow was run by Linux user `joe`, how can the system `root` user determine that a VM is indeed running?

```sh
IMAGE_NAME="ubuntu:20.10"
DOCKER_ARGS="--rm -i --privileged"

cat <<"EOF" | docker run ${DOCKER_ARGS} ${IMAGE_NAME}
set -ex
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libvirt0 virt-manager

libvirtd --daemon
virtlogd --daemon

virsh net-list --name | fgrep default || virsh net-start default

virt-install \
  --name MyFedora \
  --memory 1024 \
  --disk path=/tmp/myFedora.img,size=10 \
  --network network=default \
  --os-variant fedora28 \
  --cdrom /opt/joe/Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-34-1.2.iso \
  --noautoconsole \
  --debug

virsh list --all

sleep infinity

EOF
```

Given that the `libvirtd` socket that `joe` is running against only exists inside the docker container, how does `root` find `joe`'s VM?

Comment: i am unsure, but it should be possible to deny sub virtualisation, as in the beginning they used lxc and there is it possible to deny that

Comment: root will see the qemu-system-x86 process running. (Btw, the ability to run docker allows to become root on the host, unless SELinux or AppArmor prevents some of it. so joe <=> root means joe is expected to do responsible things).

Comment: @A.B How can the pid of the `qemu-system-x86` process be used to track down and apply policy to the VM?

Comment: You should explain in the question what's the problem you are intending to solve. Else this can become an XY problem: https://xyproblem.info .

Comment: @A.B My comment was rhetorical in nature. The point being that -- unless `qemu-system-x86` is special; and it may be, idk -- having pid doesn't generally tell us very much about what might hiding behind the pid unless there is a viable mechanism for reverse-lookup into the application space.